# Why am I getting "Error: download preflight failed for [node version]"

Tags: node.js, angular

I read I can simply change versions locally with `n`, which I need to do to run Angular apps locally.  But my connection is timing out and I'm not able to change the version of node locally with the `n` plugin.

```
% sudo n 16.16.0
Password:
  installing : node-v16.16.0
curl: (35) error:02FFF03C:system library:func(4095):Operation timed out

  Error: download preflight failed for '16.16.0' (https://nodejs.org/dist/v16.16.0/node-v16.16.0-darwin-arm64.tar.xz)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to append `v` before the node version.

Despite documentation showing you can simply specify the version, based on the bug report [here](https://github.com/tj/n/issues/642), without the `v` it won't find the version.

Try `sudo n v16.16.0` and see if that works.